# Render List returned via JQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, freemarker

On the server side, I have a list into a bean.
On the Client side, I use:

```
function callJava() {   
 $.getJSON("../reference/test", { name: $('#name').val()}, function(result) {
                         // result is a bean that has a list 
           alert(result.fooList.length);
 });
 }
```

I need to be able to render this list later via FreeMarker.
What is killing me when I replaced this list with a String variable, it works fine like:

```
function callJava() {   
 $.getJSON("../reference/test", { name: $('#name').val()}, function(result) {
 alert(result.stringVariable)

 });
 }
```

How could I deal with the string into that bean !!

Comment: It's is not at all clear what it is you're trying to do.  It's also not clear what FreeMarker has to do with this.

Comment: Ok . Let me clarify it more . I need to pass a list of String from java class to the view . Then I need to render this list  somehow . Currently I just need to print the values of this list of String . I use JQuery and I have succeeded to render a string variable returned from java class into my view . Now um trying to do the same but over a List .

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is manipulate the elements of the list:

```
function callJava() {   
   $.getJSON("../reference/test", { name: $('#name').val()}, function(result) {
     for (var i = 0; i < result.fooList.length; ++i)
       alert(result.fooList[i]);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Still it doesn't go through the for loop as well no java script error I get .

Comment: If it's really an array, and if the length is greater than zero, then that definitely will "go through the loop".

Comment: I have set a break point @ Server side and I ensured that this array is of length 4 . I have smth I didn't clarify ; that the list is a Scala list which is returned from the server side :)

Comment: If your problem is on the client side, then that's probably where you should focus some more debugging ...

Comment: HelloZ Pointy ,Actually I have just solved this issue .As I have told you the issue was on the SCALA List .I have used array and it works SUPER :) . Appreciate ur support .

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have just an update over my question is that the list I'm trying to return from the server side is a SCALA list . I have solved this issue by using an array instead of JAVA . and it works fine by using the following as **Pointy** said :

```
function callJava() {   
   $.getJSON("../reference/test", { name: $('#name').val()}, function(result) {
     for (var i = 0; i < result.fooList.length; ++i)
       alert(result.fooList[i]);
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you capture the JSON response and post it? The jQuery getJSON method will silently swallow any parsing errors from malformed JSON. That is probably what happened.